# Is there a way to allow a certain block to be placed in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to organize the work of mail on the map with the adventure mode and the Ender Mail mod. Is there a way to allow a player in adventure mode to put and destroy a certain block always and everywhere, in my case this is a endermail:package block from the mod. If not, then perhaps a command would help, which would allow you to place a block from the inventory at certain coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

You can allow a specific block item to be placeable on certain blocks by using the [CanPlaceOn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags#:%7E:text=Example-,canplaceon,-This%20tag%20is) NBT tag.

There is currently no way to make it placeable on all of the blocks without adding all of the blocks to an item tag ([see this feedback post](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/7103955734157-CanPlaceOn-All-CanDestroy-All)).

Answer (score -1):

I found a video on Youtube that shows how to do it. Basically, you have to download a code generator for Minecraft.
There you can pick the block you want the people to be able to place, and let it be able to be placed in Adventure mode in Minecraft.
Here's [the link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fb4fejBdgp4), and [this is the link to MCStacker](https://mcstacker.net/).

I'm pretty sure the website just generates a code for you and you have to put it in yourself with a Command Block.